# Hide the mouse in a Mac application after not moving it

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nscursor

I am currently making a slideshow application for Mac using Swift. In this application I want to hide the mouse while the slideshow is running and the mouse has not been moved for a while, pretty much like it is done in Quick Time Player for example.

Now I have tried a bunch of ways using `NSCursor.hide()` and `NSCursor.unhide()` as well as `NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves()`, but non of it quite worked.

Firstly I failed to make it call the mouseMoved function in my main ViewController and secondly `NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves()` doesn't always seem to work even though I have not touched my trackpad at all. It is right after the code that changes the image in the slideshow and I see the image being changed, but using the debugger it doesn't stop on that line of code when the cursor isn't hidden.

Would someone be able to show me a general way how to get this to work? I'm pretty sure this is not such an exotic thing to do and there is much easier ways to do it than what I am trying.

The following is what I've tried:

```
import Cocoa

class DiashowViewController: NSViewController {

    enum DiashowState {
        case playing
        case paused
        case stopped
    }

    var files: [URL]?
    var diaTimer = Timer()
    var diashowState: DiashowState = .stopped

    var mouseTimer = Timer()

    @IBOutlet weak var diaView: NSImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.

        }
    }

    func playDiashow() {
        if diashowState == .paused {
            diaTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.changeDia), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            diashowState = .playing
            NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(true)
        }
    }

    func playDiashow(withFiles files: [URL]) {
        stopDiashow()

        self.files = files
        diashowState = .paused

        playDiashow()
        changeDia()
    }

    func pauseDiashow() {
        if diashowState == .playing {
            diaTimer.invalidate()
            diashowState = .paused
        }
    }

    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("MOUSE MOVED")
    }

    func stopDiashow() {
        pauseDiashow()
        diaView.image = nil
        files = nil
        diashowState = .stopped
    }

    func changeDia() {
        if diashowState == .playing {
            let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(files!.count)))
            let thisDiaURL = files![i]
            let thisDia = NSImage(contentsOf: thisDiaURL)
            thisDia?.size = NSSize(width: (thisDia?.representations.first?.pixelsWide)!, height: (thisDia?.representations.first?.pixelsHigh)!)
            diaView.image = thisDia
            NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(true)
            print("HIDE MOUSE")
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please paste code of what you tried

Comment: Sorry, there you go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To receive `mouseMoved` events you need to add a `NSTrackingArea` to the view and as you have probably discovered the `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves` setting is single shot and needs to be reasserted after a mouse move in that state.

Rather than trying to unravel your code i made a demo project where I setup a window with a view and a button. The view changes color from red to green to show state.

[image]

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var xview: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        xview.wantsLayer = true
    }

    //1.
    var isPresentingSlideshow = false
    @IBAction func toggle(_ sender: Any) {

        if(isPresentingSlideshow) {
            isPresentingSlideshow = false
            xview.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
            teardownTracking()
        }
        else {
            isPresentingSlideshow = true
            xview.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
            setupTracking()
        }
    }

    //2.
    var trackingArea:NSTrackingArea?
    func setupTracking() {
        let area = NSTrackingArea(rect: xview.bounds, options: [.activeAlways,.mouseEnteredAndExited,.mouseMoved,.inVisibleRect]  , owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        xview.addTrackingArea(area)
        trackingArea = area
    }

    //3.
    func teardownTracking() {
        if let trackingArea = trackingArea {
            xview.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
            self.trackingArea = nil
            NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(false)
        }
    }

    //4.
    var cursorHideState = false
    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseMoved(with: event)

        if !cursorHideState {
            cursorHideState = true
            //5.
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                [weak self] in
                if let _ = self?.trackingArea {
                    NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(true)
                    self?.cursorHideState = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What going on here is.

1. Simple toggle action to flip between playing/not-playing state and reflect that in the color state.
2. Adds a `NSTrackingArea` to the view. The owner is this view controller so it will receive the `mouseMoved:` event. The option `.mouseMoved` is required to set this up.
3. Removes the tracking area from the view when the slide show isn't playing and sets `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves` to false.
4. The `mouseMoved:` handler
5. The `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves` is set true after two seconds as long as the tracking area exists and its not already waiting. Note the weak reference to `self` prevents a possible retain cycle here.

This isn't perfect as you might find that the cursor hides once after leaving your window but should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for!
Could one use a Timer instead of DispatchQueue or is there a good reason to use it over a Timer?

Comment: You could use a timer here too. My preference is for DispatchQueue as the retain semantics are a little clearer IMO. But to each their own :-)

Comment: I have tried your solution and it seems to work wonderfully except for that a call of `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves`doesn't seem to hide the cursor. I only occasionally see the cursor being hidden. I know that the function is called though because the program stops in the right moments for a breakpoint I put on it and a call of `print`right below it also gets called at the right times.
Any idea?

Comment: I don't know . Are you dead sure your mouse isn't moving/moved at the point the call is made ? My test was to shift the mouse into the tracking area and then hands off and wait.

Comment: Yes, I am. I test it just like you do. I just tested it printing something every time the mouse moves and there is definitely no movement after calling `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves`, but the cursor is hidden only on very rare occasions. I had a similar issue earlier when I was hiding the cursor every time the picture in the slideshow changed.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much!